# Why does Ruby keep the relationship to a hash when initializing with variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

maybe I am used to the initialState from React, but I tried doing something similar in Ruby and I noticed it updates the hash everywhere I initialized it.

Here's an example:

```
iniatializing_hash = {likes_count: 0, comments_count: 0}
hash_that_uses_initializer = {first: iniatializing_hash, second: iniatializing_hash}

# update first
hash_that_uses_initializer[:first][:likes_count] += 1
hash_that_uses_initializer[:first][:comments_count] += 1

# expect both first and second were updated
puts "first: #{hash_that_uses_initializer[:first].inspect} and second: #{hash_that_uses_initializer[:second].inspect}"
# returns first: {:likes_count=>1, :comments_count=>1} and second: {:likes_count=>1, :comments_count=>1}
```

I'm guessing this happens because it keeps the connection to the place in memory the hash is loaded.

Is there another elegant way to use an 'initialState' hash in Ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: Both keys in `hash_that_uses_initializer` have the same object as its value, so if the object is altered both values will be altered. You might not expect that but it's intrinsic with the design of the Ruby language. To change only one of the values you need to make the values different objects. For example, `h = { :a => 1 }; g = h.dup #=> { :a=>1 }`. Then `h.object_id #=> 1440` and `g.object_id #=> 1460`. If we change `h`, say `h[:a]=>2`, then `g` is unchanged (`g #=> { :a=>1 }`). Be careful if the hash values are not simple literals...

Comment: ...For example, if `h = { :a => [1,2] }; g = h.dup` and we execute `h[:a][1] = 3`, then `h #=> {:a=>[1, 3]}`, but `g #=> {:a=>[1, 3]}`. That's because `h[:a]` and `g[:a]` are still the same object (`h[:a].object_id #=> 1540; g[:a].object_id #=> 1540`).  After `g = h.dup` we would have to write `g[:a] = g[:a].dup`. Then after `h[:a][1] = 3` we would see that `g #=> { :a=>[1,2] }`. Now `g[:a].object_id #=> 60`. See [this article](https://medium.com/rubycademy/the-complete-guide-to-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby-part-i-91be8b9daafd).

Comment: Thanks @CarySwovelandI actually was looking for dup on the docs, and did not see it (was end of the day!). It's dangerous practice in short, I can easily see another dev coming in and making an initialState hash deeper without realizing the short comings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are passed by reference. When you assign `iniatializing_hash`, it does not assign a copy of the hash - it assigns a pointer. When you change the values of the hash that you assigned to `:first`, you're also changing the values of the hash at `:second` because they're both the same hash.

You can prove they're the same location in memory by calling `object_id` method on the object:

```
echo('same hash') if iniatializing_hash.object_id == hash_that_uses_initializer[:first].object_id == hash_that_uses_initializer[:second].object_id
```

If you want a copy, then you need a deep copy.

```
def deep_copy(initial_hash)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(initial_hash))
end

hash_that_uses_initializer = {first: deep_copy(iniatializing_hash), second: deep_copy(iniatializing_hash)}
```

Now the hash stored at `:first` and the `:second` will be completely different from each other and different from `iniatializing_hash`

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I have never heard of Marshal before. My guess is this is not the best ruby practice if we have to use a custom method to make a deep copy.